# Total sum of two variable values from two SQL query statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two sql queries to have the results.

```
$sql1="SELECT bom.`OUTPRDNAME`, SUM(bom.TOTALVALUE * b_master.calculation) / 100 + SUM(bom.TOTALVALUE) AS TOTAL1, b_master.`PRDSTGCD`, b_master.`calculation` FROM bom INNER JOIN b_master ON bom.`PRDSTGCD`=b_master.`PRDSTGCD` WHERE BOPPRDCD='$BOPPRDCD' AND OUTPRDCD='$BOPPRDCD' GROUP BY `OUTPRDNAME` ORDER BY PRDSTGDES";
```

```
$sql2="SELECT bom.`OUTPRDSRL`,bom.`BOPPRDCD`,bom.`OUTPRDNAME`,bom.`PRDSTGCD`, SUM(bom.`REQQTY`) AS RTOTAL, SUM(bom.`TOTALVALUE`) AS RRTOTAL, SUM(bom.TOTALVALUE * b_master.calculation) / 100 + SUM(bom.TOTALVALUE) AS TOTAL2, b_master.`PRDSTGCD`, b_master.`calculation` FROM bom INNER JOIN b_master ON bom.`PRDSTGCD`=b_master.`PRDSTGCD` WHERE BOPPRDCD='$BOPPRDCD' AND OUTPRDCD='$OUTPRDCD' GROUP BY `OUTPRDNAME` ORDER BY PRDSTGDES";
```

Above table result is

| TOTAL | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| RM | 59,057.24 |
| PM | 1,520.93 |

I want to have a total of TOTAL1 FROM sql1 and TOTAL2 from sql2.

```
TOTAL  | 60578.17
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your queries work you will want to do something like this:

```sql
WITH sql3 AS (
sql1
UNION ALL
sql2
)

SELECT SUM(VALUE) AS TOTAL FROM sql3
```

Comment: Please explain the logic as I am not able to get the result as desired.